# prevent exceeding the boundaries of my page when using iscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

When I scroll up (dragging down the mouse pointer) I'm exceeding the first line of text and I see the gray area. I'm using .attr('data-iscroll', '') on a div that i have created dynamically.
how can i prevent the page from slideing and exceeding the boundaries of my page?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the bounce property to false e.g.:

```
myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', { 
    mouseWheel: true,
    scrollbars: true,
    bounce: false
});
```